# MPMoviePlayerController Done button unresponsive in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

All,
   The Done button in MPMoviePlayerController dismisses the control in portrait mode.
   However, both the Done and Toggle full screen button become unresponsive when i rotate to landscape. 
    My app is a very very simple app and just has didRotatefromInterfaceOrientation method where i change the movie frame width and height to landscape and change the origin to match landscapemode.

`- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    // Update the frame of the view.
    CGRect newFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

```
newFrame.origin.x = - (newFrame.size.width / 2);
newFrame.origin.y = - (newFrame.size.height / 2);

[[self view] setBounds:newFrame];
[[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake( [[self view] bounds].size.width / 2, [[self view] bounds].size.height / 2)];
[self view].userInteractionEnabled = YES;

// Update the frame of the movie player.
newFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
if( fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    newFrame.size.width = newFrame.size.height;
    newFrame.size.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width;
}
newFrame.origin.x = - (newFrame.size.width / 2);
newFrame.origin.y = - (newFrame.size.height / 2);
[[[self moviePlayer] view] setFrame:newFrame];
[[[self moviePlayer] view ] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES ];
```

}`

Comment: Why are you changing values on rotate programmatically?

Comment: Cause if i don't then the view shifts off screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem here was that i was rotating the view and resizing it in `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation.
You are not required to do that as the movie player automatically does that for you. 
Resizing and rotating the frame actually got the button confused and hence did not receive touch events when tapped.